# gdb need to run as root. emacs gdb-many-windows

Tags: emacs, gdb

I use gdb-many-windows in emacs as normal user. But the program need to run as root. Can i change to root in emacs before run gdb-many-windows? Is there other way to solve this problem?

Update: Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `Meta-X gdb`, `emacs` allows you to change the `gdb` command it will invoke.

Just change it to `sudo gdb --annotate=3 ...`

Update: as matt comments, this is still quite insecure. Better make it

```
sudo /usr/bin/gdb -ex 'set auto-load-scripts no' --annotate=3 ...
```

An even better approach might be to change your setup such that the program you are debugging does not need to run as root in the first place. Perhaps you could use [fakeroot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fakeroot) instead?

Update 2: sudo appears to interfere with emacs terminal handling. In particular, it tries to read password from `/dev/tty` and doesn't get input from emacs mini-buffer.

The solution is to allow yourself to invoke GDB without password via sudo. Something like this (in `/etc/sudoers`) should work:

```
your_user_id ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/gdb
```

Comment: unfortunately running gdb as root as well is a fairly bad idea (TM) because of things like the .debug_gdb_scripts section.  You may want to set auto-load-scripts no

Comment: @matt, thanks for your comment. I've updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: @Employed Russian, when i type alt+x gdb, sudo gdb then type the passwd. It just stuck there. I can use "sudo gdb" in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

A solution not mentioned here is to have your build script set the setuid bit on your binary and set the ownership to root

```
chmod u+s binaryname
chmod g+s binaryname
chown root:root binaryname
```

that's probably more secure then either of the two answers (although it'll let anybody that has execute permission run the file as root, that may not be what you want...)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a way to do this with emacs 25 without tinkering with sudoers. You need to go to any buffer in emacs (I usually use a file from my project), do 'M-x cd', select '/sudo::/' - this changes the default directory. Then, when you run 'M-x gdb', gdb will run under sudo (you will be prompted for your password). See also here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/DdAev2pWJMw

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to run emacs as root, which will cause gdb (and any other process you spawn) to run as root.

Comment: Yeah, this is the way i use now. But it is not very convenient :-(

Comment: Running emacs as root is a *really bad idea (TM)*